# ¿Porque mi app se cierra cuando la voy a emular?

Tags: android-studio, android-layout

Mis apps se cierran mas que todo cuando son aplicaciones que tienen que ver con imágenes,
y dice lo siguiente : unfortunately app stopped.
reviso el Logcat en la parte de Error y encuentro esta linea.

```
at com.example.borrar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
```

si doy clic a esa linea me muestra mi linea de código

```
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
```

aqui todo el mensaje de la excepcion:

```
03-21 02:18:00.097 1170-1170/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.borrar/com.example.borrar.MainActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class ImageButton
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2059)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2084)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:130)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1195)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #21: Error inflating class ImageButton
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:704)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:746)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:749)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:489)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:396)
    at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:352)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:555)
    at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:161)
    at com.example.borrar.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:14)
```

Comment: ya lo coloque toda la excepcion

Comment: Puede ser por muchas razones. Si pudieras actualizar colocando el Activity donde te esta formando el problema se te podría resolver!

Comment: Comparto la solución por si alguien algún dia tiene este problema.el error esta en que cuando copias y pegas imagenes a la carpeta drawable, te da dos opciones o formatos por asi decirlo la primera opcion es la que te da por defecto ej:(img arbol -24) y la otra es (img arbol) escoge la segunda opcion